# How can I use ijson

Tags: python, json

I would like to extract abstractText from a json file which is very large . I use the lib ijson from python but i can't find the right way to extract what I want .
The structure of json file is

`{'articles'=[{"abstractText":"text..", "journal":"journal..", "meshMajor":["mesh1",...,"meshN"],
"pmid":"PMID", "title":"title..", "year":"YYYY"},..., {..}]`

Could you help me ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: When i interpet the above code , there is this error . UnexpectedSymbol: Unexpected symbol "'" at 1

Comment: It is  an error from jason file ,isn't it ??

Comment: I am newbie so I ask you something strange. If I use jackson from java the problem will be fixed ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not valid JSON. The single quoted `'articles'` must be double quoted `"articles"` and there should be a `:` instead of `=` after `"articles"`. Assuming that it is correct, you should use:

```
json["articles"][0]["abstractText"]
```

Edit: A complete example for `ijson` library:

```
import ijson
f = open('json.txt')
objects = ijson.items(f, 'articles.item')
for obj in objects:
    print obj["abstractText"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('file_name.json', 'rb') as input_file:
    parser = ijson.parse(input_file)
    for parent, data_type, value in parser:
        print('parent={}, data_type={}, value={}'.format(parent, data_type, value))
```